# change how a character is displayed

Tags: conceal

Is it possible to change how a character is displayed?

I explain better, I want to replace the character '*' with math unicode '∗' [U+2217]. This should affect only the way the character is displayed not the file content.

Note: I have already tried to use the conceal feature, however I am not really satisfied by the result.

I would like to have a behaviour similar to listchars and list
for example listchars=space:.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: ops I didn't check the 'concealcursor' option! I solved and got exactly the behaviour. Solution    `syntax match Normal /\*/ conceal cchar=∗` and  `set conceallevel=1` and   `set concealcursor=ni`

Comment: @nicmus You should post that as an answer if it solves the issue for you. Answering your own question is allowed!

Answer (score 8):

So as suggested I will give the solution I found.

After having

```
set conceallevel=1
set concealcursor=ni
```

there are two ways to achieve the result:

1) using `:syntax match`

```
:syntax match Conceal /\*/ conceal cchar=∗
```

2) using `matchadd`

```
:call matchadd('Conceal','\*',10,-1,{'conceal': '∗'})
```

Note

- 10 is the priority (default is 10)
- -1 is the match ID (see `help matchadd`)

You might also consider

```
:hi! link Conceal Normal
```

to link the syntax highlighting of Conceal group to Normal group.